# find a nested div tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have two div tags like bellow:

```
<body>
   <div id="divParent">
      <div id="divChild"></div>
   </div>
</body>
```

How can I get the divChild using JavaScript?

Comment: Will your actual elements have IDs or is this just for demo purposes and you want to traverse the DOM?

Comment: Read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById

Comment: @MJ_Developer updated answer to show how to hide/show child div

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
divChild = document.getElementById("divChild");
```

or if you didn't have the child id:

```
divChild = document.getElementById("divParent").children[0];
```

Edit:

you can hide or show child with:

```
divChild.style.display = "none";//hide
divChild.style.display = "block";//show
```

Comment: If `divChild` has inner multiple `<div>` how to get it? Will it be still based on the `divParent` because it is the parent of them all? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
 var myDiv = document.getElementById('divChild');
```

Then you can get the contents like this

```
 var content = myDiv.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 1):

`var el = document.getElementById("divChild")`

Answer (score 1):

```
var div = document.getElementById("divChild");
```